# Parsing RSS Translation with Google Scripts

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, scripting, rss

i am trying to use the following script in google scripts to get a RSS translation service.

The code.gs is the following :

```
    function doGet() {

  var fromLang = "en";    
  var toLang   = "es";    
  var rssFeed  = "https://XXXXXX.com/XXXX/feed/";  

  var feed = parseRSS(rssFeed, fromLang, toLang);      
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(feed)
           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);    
}


function parseRSS(feed, fromLang, toLang) {

  var id = Utilities.base64Encode(feed + fromLang + toLang);

  // Cache the RSS feeds for an hour
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
  var rss   = cache.get(id);

  if (rss != null) {
    return rss;
  }

  var item, date, title, link, desc, guid; 

  var txt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(feed).getContentText();
  var doc = Xml.parse(txt, false);  

  title = doc.getElement().getElement("channel").getElement("title").getText();

  // The RSS Feed is translated using Google Translate
  rss = '<rss version="2.0">';
  rss += "<channel><title>";
  rss += LanguageApp.translate(title, fromLang, toLang);
  rss += " (" + title + ")</title>";

  var items = doc.getElement().getElement("channel").getElements("item");   

  // Parsing single items in the RSS Feed
  for (var i in items) {

    try {

      item  = items[i];

      title = item.getElement("title").getText();
      link  = item.getElement("link").getText();
      date  = item.getElement("pubDate").getText();
      desc  = item.getElement("description").getText();

      guid  = Utilities.base64Encode(link + fromLang + toLang);

      title = LanguageApp.translate(title, fromLang, toLang);
      desc  = LanguageApp.translate(desc,  fromLang, toLang, 
                                       {contentType: "html"});

      rss += "<item>";
      rss += "  <title>"   + title + "</title>";
      rss += "  <link>"    + link  + "</link>";
      rss += "  <pubDate>" + date  + "</pubDate>";
      rss += "  <guid>"    + guid  + "</guid>";
      rss += "  <description><![CDATA[" + desc + "]]></description>";
      rss += "</item>";

    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
  }

  rss += "</channel></rss>";

  cache.put(id, rss, 3600);
  return rss;

}
```

This script works and gives me a link to "https://script.googleusercontent.com". 
Some sites dont recognize this as a RSS feed properly. How can i get it to work as a XML or HTML and a W3 valid RSS Feed?

Comment: I don't completely understand  your goal. After getting the link what would you like to do? Pass that info to a site you created? Because for what I can see in your example code, it returns an XML, therefore you can get it for further use.

Comment: My goal is to get a Valid W3 RSS Feed validated on "https://validator.w3.org/feed/" when i add the script.googleusercontent... it doesnt work at all. How does it actually returns a XML to you ? I click on parse but end up with the following error : Error DNS: http://undefined (línea 27)

Answer (score 0):

When using the [Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) provided by Apps Script. Keep in mind the redirects conditions, which are mentioned in the docs:

> For security reasons, content returned by the Content service isn't
> served from script.google.com, but instead redirected to a one-time
> URL at script.googleusercontent.com. This means that if you use the
> Content service to return data to another application, you must ensure
> that the HTTP client is configured to follow redirects. For example,
> in the cURL command line utility, add the flag -L. Check the
> documentation for your HTTP client for more information on how to
> enable this behavior.

Therefore, when testing it  [HERE](https://validator.w3.org/feed/) throws you that error because you're trying to get the info from an external source that doesn't follow redirects.

In your `rssFeed` variable, you could test it with the URL provided in the docs: `http://xkcd.com/rss.xml`.

To try different [MYME types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output.html#setmimetypemimetype), change this line of code:

### from

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(feed)
           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);
```

### To

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(feed)
           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
```

### Edit

If you want to save a file in your drive your `doGet()` function now should look like this

```
function doGet() {

  var fromLang = "en";    
  var toLang   = "es";    
  var rssFeed  = "http://xkcd.com/rss.xml";  

  var feed = parseRSS(rssFeed, fromLang, toLang);   
  DriveApp.createFile("rssTest", feed, MimeType.HTML);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(feed)
           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);    
}
```

Comment: I did tried with different rssfeeds (variables) in this case, and app deploys perfectly exactly as the situation above mentioned. 

Also tried with XML and RSS and they give same result in my case the undefined error on line 27 
"Error DNS: undefined (línea 27)" 

I am still getting the exact same error because of the redirection, how could i fix this?

The error only shows up when parsing, doget shows no error at all.

Comment: I tried the exaple exactly as google described it in the post you mentioned. It works perfectly fine, exactly as the RSS Language Translation Script i provided. But still is as "https://script.googleusercontent.com" and makes it useless.... how can i save this to a XML ? do i have to add any code ?

Comment: As a workaround, if it fits for you, you could save the XML file in your Drive using [DriveApp.createFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename,-content,-mimetype)

Comment: This should work perfectly for me...
I have edited the first part of the code and added the following :
  var feed = parseRSS(rssFeed, fromLang, toLang);      
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(feed)
           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);    
  DriveApp.createFile('New HTML File', MimeType.HTML);
}

But I am still getting the following error (now on line 28)
Error DNS: undefined (línea 28)

Being the issue -> var txt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(feed).getContentText();

Comment: Ok i followed your edit and finally got the file on my G Drive as HTML in XML and RSS format... but for some reason i am not getting validated in W3. This is the link i get https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NEVHYvV8ZI73z9KJum1f0AP4voHQnNkt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Using the [Validate by direct input](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and copying directly to it the info in your generated file, I noticed the ***<img> tags*** are breaking your markup, without them the validation works. I would recommend you to open a new question about it if you really need those ***<img> tags*** because your main problem about Google Apps Script was solved.